# Very basic Objective-C/C Problem

Tags: objective-c

Here's my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void PrintPathInfo() {
    const char *path = [@"~" fileSystemRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"My home folder is at '%@'", path);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    PrintPathInfo();

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my problem:
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

I really think the problem is my NSLog but I don't know how to solve it.

Could someone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

%@ is for objects. (Like NSString).  for const char* you will want the good old %s from the c's printf format codes.

See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

For the format specifies and their meanings

Answer (score 8):

path is not an NSString, which is why that crashes.  %@ in a formatting string expects an object, and asks it for a description to get a string to print... because you are using a C style string, you need to use the standard C string formatters OR convert the const char * back to an NSString using the initWithCString:encoding: class method of NSString.

Staying with a const char *, you can use:

```
 NSLog(@"My home folder is at '%s'", path);
```

which would work.

Comment: I think this is right, you can't pass a char* to a method that takes an NSString.  There are ways to convert a char* to an NSString though.